# How to setup OpenCart into Heroku by Best Practice

Tags: php, heroku, opencart

I have no idea which is how to setup OpenCart into Heroku from Github Integration.

I am stuck in `Delete install folder after install complete` this step.

Step 1

> Download the OpenCart and git push the upload folder to github repo

Step 2

> In the Heroku Web Panel, point to master branch for Heroku deploy

Step 3

> Through the composer file to successful deploy and view app

Step 4

> Start to install step by step about OpenCart Installation. e.g DB connection..

Step 5

> At the last step successful to install, OpenCart remind me to delete the `install folder`

How should I delete the `install folder` ?

Comment: `heroku login;
heroku run bash; rm ...`

Comment: Should I need to slugIgnore the install folder and delete install folder ?
Another issue is how to check opencart installation can access to write code in the config file ?